# DropDownList controls in panel losing values on postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback, viewstate

Apologies if this is forgetful late-night coding, but....

I've got some dynamically populated DropDownList controls that are being added to a panel at runtime. I've had the panel with and without explicitly enabling its viewstate.

If I declare and populate them inside the usual

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

block in the Page_Load then they simply don't exist on Postback - I try to iterate through the panel's controls collection and it's empty.

If I declare and populate them separately in the page's OnInit then they exist, but lose their values.

How do I get them to both exist and retain their values?

Comment: You have recreate all dynamically created controls on every postback with the same id as before in `page_init` or `page_load`(at the latest). Then they retain their values across postback(with enabled `ViewState`).

Comment: Did you enable Viewstate tracking check this [SO solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/623828/125551) and [MSDN content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.trackviewstate.aspx)